# Pitfalls of inheritence and nested names

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, name-lookup

I've come across a peculiar case while designing my C++ object inheritance tree in a project. I expected the below to fail:

```
struct A {
    protected:
    struct C { };
};

struct B: A { 
    struct C { };
};
```

But, this compiles just fine. Is this like an override? I can see how this isn't ambiguous because they can be specified as `A::C` and `B::C`, but how does this act in polymorphic cases? Will it call the prescribed type's C or the instance's type's C? As in, suppose this code below works and `func` exists in both implementations of C:

```
A x = B();
decltype(x)::C::func();
```

which C would have their function called? More generally, is their a resource that describes how code snippets like these resolve?

Comment: Your example creates `x` as having type `A` (and slices a `B` to initlalise it).   In the next statement, it is irrelevant that `x` was initialised by slicing a `B`, since its type is `A`.   So `decltype(x)::C::func()` will resolve to `A::C::func()`   (and then compile or not depending on access control and context it is used).

Comment: @Peter. That makes sense. What if `A x = B();` was changed to`B x = B(); A &y = x;`? Would that also cause slicing?

Comment: `B x = B()` will not cause slicing (it is equivalent to `B x` without the temporary [assuming that copying an object creates an equal object, etc]).   `y` will be able to access `A::C` but not `B::C`.   Given a reference to an `A`, the compiler has no information that allows it implicit to access any name in `B`, even if the referred object is actually a `B`.   Given a `B` (or a reference to `B`) the name `C` in `B` hides the name `C` from `A`  - it is only possible to access `A`s `C` using specific scoping (like `B::C` or `B::A::C` or (within a member of `B`) `A::C`).

Comment: @Peter That's what I was expecting. Thanks :)

Comment: Runtime polymorphism works at... run time. Names are bound at compile time. Type names don't have runtime polymorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fine, because you have two unrelated `struct C`: the one is `B::C` and the other `B::A::C`.  `C` is just their shortcut name.

If you would have a static function f() defined in each C,  you would be able to call it from outside the struct and without any object, as you have shown in your code:

```
A a =  B();              // the type of a is A (B is sliced, by the way) 
decltype(a)::C::f();     // so this calls A::C::f()
```

Now for the sake of completeness, here a more developed example that shows that at no point there is an ambiguity:

```
struct A {
   struct C { static void f() { cout << "A::C::f" <<endl; } };
};

struct B: A {
    C c1;            // the only C known here is A::C
    struct C { static void f() { cout << "B::C::f" <<endl; }}; // now B::C hides A::C
    C c2;            // so here the closest C known is B::C
    A::C c3;         // and here I can be explicit about the C I want
    using D=A::C;    // and here another way to be explicit:
    D c4; 
};

int main() {    
    B  b; 
    decltype(b.c1)::C::f();    // A
    decltype(b.c2)::C::f();    // B  
}
```

[online demo](https://ideone.com/gdSKAS)

Comment: So as types they won't have naming conflicts, but do you think this what result in unexpected behavior in some way?

Comment: @AnthonyMonterrosa No, I don't think that this will give unexpected behavior.  The choice of the type is always done at compile time, not at runtime.  If you declare a C object, the compiler must know which C is meant (e.g. in order to generate the code that will reserve enough space for the object and construct it).

Comment: I see. Thank you for your comprehensive example! It helps quite a bit to see the edge cases. Knowing it's always compile time also reinforces the semantics I already know.